# How to delete a service account in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

By mistake I created a service account to give admin permission for dashboard. But now I am unable to delete it.

The reason I want to get rid of that service account is if I follow the steps here https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard. When I jump to the URL it doesn't ask for config/token anymore.

```
$ kubectl get serviceaccount --all-namespaces | grep dashboard

NAMESPACE     NAME                   SECRETS   AGE

kube-system   kubernetes-dashboard   1         44m

$ kubectl delete serviceaccount kubernetes-dashboard

Error from server (NotFound): serviceaccounts "kubernetes-dashboard" not found
```

Comment: How are you trying to delete it?  What happens when you do?

Comment: 88e9fe562973:my_pods gauta$ kubectl get serviceaccount --all-namespaces | grep-i dashboard
NAMESPACE     NAME                   SECRETS   AGE
kube-system   kubernetes-dashboard   1         44m
88e9fe562973:my_pods gauta$



kubectl delete serviceaccount kubernetes-dashboard
Error from server (NotFound): serviceaccounts "kubernetes-dashboard" not found

Answer (score 43):

You have to specify the namespace when deleting it:

```
kubectl delete serviceaccount -n kube-system kubernetes-dashboard
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using microk8s:
do, ' microk8s enable dns ' command and this should fixed the cluster dns missing issue.
For services like minikube should work same.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33458173)